# using raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-9.3, raster-calculator

I have a combination method to combine two raster( raster x and y) . 
the method is : x+y / 1- min(|x|,|y|)
my problem is about "," character .whats the "," means in the method and  how can i use this method in raster calculator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Spatial Analyst Extension.

If I understand your question, and your method, the "," is just separating the inputs in the min function.  So, you want to find the minimum cell value from the absolute value of the x raster and the y raster.

I haven't used Raster Calculator for a while, but I don't think you can calculate the minimum cell value of a raster within the Raster Calculator.  You may have to perform that calculation separately.  One way to do this is to use the [Min](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Min) function.

If it is possible to use the min function within the Raster Calculator (again, I'm not sure if that will work and I don't have an SA license), your syntax might look something like this:

```
("X"+"Y")/(1-min(abs("X"),abs("Y"))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i'm using Spatial Analyst Extension.you say that min fuction need "," and its just separator of each raster .

Comment: your syntaxt work properly

Comment: @majid moosavi - then you need to mark the answer as correct. This will take from 0%accept rate and might get more answers to your questions. That is the way stackexchange works.